# Load only the next 10min of HTML video when it is playing - not the entire video

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

I have videos on my website with duration of almost 2h (=> large file size).

I have managed to convert them to h265 to reduce server load. To further reduce server load I also want the video to only load e.g. the next 10min from the point the user currently is at in the video (and not the entire video). Youtube is doing it this way.

The HTML preload attribute does not have this option. Is there such a feature in ffmpeg (or anywhere else)?

Thanks for a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with  "Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP". It could be implemented via javascript.
I suggest looking into [Dash.js github page](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki)